# Is there a way to capture the current cursor image in OS X

Tags: screen-capture

I'm trying to report a bug where the cursor shape matters. The two easy screen capture methods exclude the cursor:

- Command-Shift-3
- The Applications->Utilities->Grab program

With grab you can set a specific cursor, which misses the point.  Here I want to capture the cursor shape that occurs when the mouse is in a specific place in a specific application.

How can I capture the entire screen, just as I see it, including the cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CLI:

```
screencapture -T 5 -C /path/to/file.png
```

<sup>`-T <seconds>` is the delay before taking the screenshot. `-C` captures the cursor in the screenshot.</sup>

Related: [Taking a screenshot of a tooltip](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122247/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-tooltip/122254#122254)